# translation invariant of integral on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

**Problem 1**: Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, show $\int_\mathbb{R}f(t)dt=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x+t)dt,\forall x\in (-\infty, \infty)$.

**Problem 2**: Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$,show $\displaystyle \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(x+t)-f(x)|dx=0$.

My try for Problem 1:

Consider $\displaystyle \int_{\mathbb{R}}f(t)dt=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{-n}^nf(t)dt=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_n(t)dt$, where $f_n(t)=f(t)\chi_{[-n,n]}$.

And since $dt=d(x+t)$, we have $\displaystyle \int_{-n}^nf(x+t)dt=\int_{-n+x}^{n+x}f(t)dt$.

So for each $x\in (-\infty,\infty)$, 
$$
\begin{split}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(t)-f(t+x)dt &=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(t)(\chi_{[-n,n]}-\chi_{[-n+x,n+x]})dt\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(t)(\chi_{[-n,-n+x]}-\chi_{[n,n+x]})dt\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\int_\mathbb{R}\varphi_k(t)(\chi_{[-n,-n+x]}-\chi_{[n,n+x]})dt\\
&=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_\mathbb{R}\varphi_k(t)(\chi_{[-n,-n+x]}-\chi_{[n,n+x]})dt
\end{split}
$$
where $\varphi_k(t)$ is simple function pointwise converges to $f(t)$, simple function vanish out of set of finite measure, so $\varphi_k(t)(\chi_{[-n,-n+x]}-\chi_{[n,n+x]})$ vanishes when $n$ big enough(**is this right?**)

---

### Another try:

Since $f\in L^1$, $f$ is bounder a.e. so can be approximated by simple functions, and $\chi_{A+t}(x)=\chi_A(x-t)$,thus
$$\int f(t)=\lim_n\int\varphi_n=\lim_n \sum_{i=1}^nc_i\mu(E_i)=\lim_n \sum_{i=1}^nc_i\mu(E_i-x)=\int f(t+x)$$

For problem 2, I guess they share the same method.

Any help or correction about these two problems? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your solution, it's not clear to me why you can just assert that $\int_{-n}^nf(x+t)\;dt=\int_{-n+x}^{n+x}f(t)\;dt$. This seems to be essentially equivalent to what you're trying to prove.

Instead, I'd proceed in the following way: first prove that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x+t)\;dt=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(t)\;dt$ when $f=\chi_E$ is a characteristic function (this should be immediate from the translation invariance of Lebesgue measure). Then prove it for simple functions by the linearity of the integral, then for non-negative functions by approximating with simple functions and using the monotone convergence theorem, and finally for arbitrary $L^1$ functions by linearity again.

For part 2, I suggest using the fact that the set of continuous functions with compact support is dense in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$, together with the fact that a continuous compactly supported function is uniformly continuous.

Comment: let $\hat{t}=x+t$, then after change variable $\int_{-n}^nf(x+t)\;dt=\int_{-n+x}^{n+x}f(\hat{t})\;d\hat{t}$

Comment: @Benjamin: as I said in my answer, proving that this change of variables is valid for arbitrary $L^1$ functions is basically the same thing as the problem you're asked to solve.