# Show that $\lim_{t\to 0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty|f(x+t)-f(t)|\,dx=0$ without using density of continuous functions in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm trying to prove that if $f(x)$ is measurable function on $\mathbb{R}$ s.t. it is integrable on every finite interval and $\sup_{n}\int_{-n}^n|f(x)|<\infty$, then $$\lim_{t\to 0}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x+t)-f(x)|\,dx=0$$

Similar questions can be seen here: [translation invariant of integral on $\mathbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1777388/792125) and [Show that $\lim _{r \to 0} \|T_rf−f\|_{L_p} =0.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/842937/792125). But both questions use the fact that the set of continuous functions with compact support are dense in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$, so **I'd like to know a way to prove without it**, since I am learning about functions of bounded variation now, and I'm not familiar with the density property.

Here are some thoughts from mine regarding this question: I'm trying to use the difference quotient $\frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{t}$ to start with, but $f(x)$ is only required to be measurable and integrable along the whole real line, a pretty weak assumption. How can I use results from differentiation of integrable functions to prove this statement?

**Added:**
$f(x)$ is not continuous here. So my guess here is to find a continuous function $g(x)$ s.t. their distance on the domain should be less than $\varepsilon$. Then I may use maximal inequality to prove the statement. But I'm not sure how to proceed. Here I give a version of maximal inequality (can be proved using Vitali Covering) for nonnegative integrable function $|f(x)-g(x)|$ on $[0,1]$:

Define $$E(a)=\{x:\sup_{0\leq t\leq 1}\frac{1}{2t}\int_{x}^{x+t}|f(y)-g(y)|dy\ge a\}$$ then $$\mu\left(E(a)\right)\leq\frac{5}{a}\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)-g(x)|dx$$

Thank you.

Comment: _Why_ do you want to do this without using that density? That's a basic tool here. Does it bother you to approximate reals numbers by rationals?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich. I'm looking for a way without doing so. If you don't know, please do not answer.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich. Please do not downvote. I've edited the question.

Comment: Show it first for indicator functions of measurable sets. Then for simple functions. Then use the usual density argument.

Comment: @HansEngler. Hi, I'm asking for a way without the density argument. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: @Mike: Since most  arguments will be based on application of dominated convergence, why using the fact that step functions or simple functions can approximate any integrable function bothers you so much? Introducing differentiability here, if successfully, would be a circular argument since differential techniques are based on density arguments too.

Comment: @OliverDiaz: Okay, this is probably a good idea. Can you write down a sketch of the proof based on your ideas? I'm just asking for alternative ways to proof a similar statement that I listed in my post.

Comment: @OliverDiaz: Are you applying translation invariance for finite measures? I actually prefer seeing an answer about this. That may solve my confusions. Also after some searching, I find this post has a similar issue with mine: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3766780/792125. Can I apply a similar approach?

Comment: @Mike: that is a slightly different type of problem. This is closer to what I am suggesting: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3733946/prove-lim-h-rightarrow0me-deltaeh-0-for-measurable-set-e-with-fini/3734833#3734833). The second solution in this [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3734833/121671) addresses the first part of my suggestion. Then again, all this can be wrapped up with a wee bonnet as a destiny argument.

Comment: @OliverDiaz. That makes things clearer. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Mike: Great! Let me now if you can fill in the details on your own. In a sense you are trying to prove the continuity of translations circumventing the use of Lusin's theorem, just to realize that Lusin's theorem was hidden there.

Comment: @OliverDiaz $m(E+t)\to m(E)$??? Yes, in fact $m(E+t)=m(E)$. I don't see how this has any relevance to the problem. The "extension" to simple functions would be $\int\phi(x+t)\,dx=\int\phi$; how does that help?

Comment: I meant to write $m(E \Delta (E+t))$ goes to 0 as $t\rightarrow0$. I’ll edit my comment  when I get back to my computer. Thanks!

Comment: @OliverDiaz that's what I thought you probably meant, didn't want to put words in your mouth

Comment: @Mike: I edited a comment that was in error. Start with a measurable set of finite measure $E$, show that $m(E\Delta(E+t))\xrightarrow{t\rightarrow0}0$. Here you can use the inner regularity of the Lebesgue measure. Then extend this to simple functions, and by monotone convergence, extend to nonnegative integrable functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is hint in the form of a sketch of a proof:

1. For any measurable set $E$ of finite Lebesgue measure, show that
   $\lim_{t\rightarrow0}m((E+t)\Delta E)=\int|\mathbb{1}_{E+t}-\mathbb{1}_E|\,dm = 0$. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3734833/121671) is a solution that uses the inner regularity of the Lebesgue measure (see second solution).
2. Extend the result from (1) to integrable simple functions.
3. By standard monotone convergence arguments, extend the result of (2) to all integrable (positive) functions.
4. By linearity, extend the result of (3) to any integrable function. ($f=f_+-f_-$).

---

This approach is direct in the sense that you are not using "density" results: density is replace by  the regularity of the Lebesgue measure. Both things are in a way equivalent things.